# Clearing the cache/history not removing form field values

Tags: applications, safari, firefox, web-browser, browser-history

I am using Firefox and Opera in OS X 10.5.8. I have cleared the cookies, history, private data number of times. But when I visit gmail/facebook, the email ID is still auto filled up. Is there anyway to remove these values.

This is not an issue in Safari. When I reset the safari, everything gets deleted/removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clear Recent History option in Firefox doesn't seem to remove saved passwords. But you can remove them from Preferences > Security > Saved Passwords.

Comment: Still an issue in Firefox 26.0 on OS X Mavericks.